# Callback events in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to call a function in my class using callback like so:

```
//main function
function Main()
   button:setOnCallback("touch", fnName)
end

//fnName
function fnName(event)
   if event.phase == "ended" then
     //do something
   end
end
```

The callback works if I don't include the event.phase == "ended" part but I need it to specify when it should call the function. The problem is, if I include that part it won't call the entire function at all. What am I doing wrong here? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/touch/index.html) would helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `event.phase` can never be `"ended"` as per the [Corona API](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/key/phase.html) reference.

It is either `up` or `down`.

> The state of the key pressed: **`"up"`** or **`"down"`**. See *[`event.keyName`](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/key/keyName.html)* for key names.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that. Why is it's value nil though? I tried printing the value of event.phase but I'm getting nil for it.

Comment: "Key" event and "Touch" have different "event.phase" values.